# A confusion about the uniqueness of the total derivative of a map $f: \mathbb{R}^p \to \mathbb{R}^q$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

In the book of *The elements of Real Analysis* by Bartle, at page 228-229, it is given that

> Lemma: A function has at most one derivative at a point.
>
> Let $L_1$ and $L_2$ are linear functions on $\mathbb{R}^p$ to
>   $\mathbb{R}^q$ which satisfies  $$||f(x)- f(c) - L(x-c)|| \leq
>  \epsilon ||x-c||$$ when $||x-c|| < \delta$. If $L_1$ and $L_2$ are
>   different, $\exists z \in \mathbb{R}^p$ with $||z|| = 1$ s.t  $$0< ||L_1
>  (z) - L_2 (z)||.$$ Now, let $\alpha$ be a non-zero real number with
>   $\alpha < \delta$ and set $x= c + \alpha z$. It follows that $$0<
>  |\alpha| ||L_1 (z) - L_2(z)|| = ||L_1 (\alpha z)  - L_2(\alpha z)|| \\
>  \leq ||f(x) - f(c) - L_1 (x-c)|| + ||f(x)- f(c) - L_2(x-c)|| \\ \leq 2
>  \epsilon ||x-c||  = 2\epsilon |\alpha|$$ Therefore, for any $\epsilon
>  > 0$,  $$0 < ||L_1 (z) - L_2 (z)|| \leq 2\epsilon,$$ which is a contradiction.

Now, here is my questions;

1-) Why do we need $|\alpha| < \delta$ ?

2-)How did we get 
$$||L_1 (\alpha z)  - L_2(\alpha z)|| 
 \leq ||f(x) - f(c) - L_1 (x-c)|| + ||f(x)- f(c) - L_2(x-c)||$$

3-) Why is the result that we have obtained a contradiction ? I mean it contradicts with what ?

Answer (score 0):

1) The proof needs $||x-c|| < \delta$ and $||x-c|| = ||\alpha z|| = |\alpha|$ since $||z|| = 1$.

2) $L_1(\alpha z) - L_2(\alpha z) = L_1(x-c) - L_2(x-c) = (f(x) - f(c) - L_2(x-c)) - (f(x) - f(c) - L_1(x-c))$

then use triangle inequality.

3) The contradiction appears because we have shown that $0 < ||L_1 (z) - L_2 (z)|| \leq 2\epsilon$ for *any* $\epsilon > 0$, but there are clearly some values for $\epsilon$ such that $0 < 2 \epsilon < ||L_1 (z) - L_2 (z)||$  - note that $L_1(x)$ and $L_2(x)$ are independent of $\epsilon$.

Comment: Why do we need $||x-c || = |||\alpha z|$ ?